sql revoke from workbench from en rojo con el siguiente error: "is not valid at this position expecting EOF"
Hola estoy usando workbench 8.0 mysql ver 15.1 Distrib 10.4.32-MariaDb for Win64.
He creado un usuario alumno y le he dado una serie de privilegios:
create user if not exists 'alumno'@'192.168.1.144' identified by 'user1';

grant all privileges on practicas.* to 'alumno'@'192.168.1.144'; grant all privileges on practicas.personal to 'alumno'@'192.168.1.144';

Cuando intento eliminar alguno de sus privilegios:
revoke all privileges on practicas.personal from 'alumno'@'192.168.1.144';

Workbench me marca la palabra from en rojo con el siguiente error: "is not valid at this position expecting EOF"
La sintaxis del comando creo que es la correcta. Si compilo este comando revoke aun mostrandome ese mensaje de error Me funciona correctamente. Veo con SHOW GRANTS FOR 'alumno'@'192.168.1.144'; que realmente sí me ha eliminado ese permiso.
Alguna idea de por que me aparece el mensaje de error dentro de Workbench sobre la palabra from dentro del comando revoke?
Gracias.

Parece un bug en el wb, o  que estás usando una versión vieja que no reconoce esa sintaxis. Lo importante es que el motor la ejecuta sin problemas.
